# Does $(X \perp Y\mid Z) \ \& \ (X \perp W \mid Z) \implies X \perp (Y,W) \mid Z$ hold?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I know that $ X \perp (Y,W) \mid Z \implies (X \perp Y\mid Z) \ \& \ (X \perp W \mid Z)$ but does the converse hold? i.e. does:

$$(X \perp Y\mid Z) \ \& \ (X \perp W \mid Z) \implies X \perp (Y,W) \mid Z$$

Hold? If not is there a counter example?

My intuition says it does not because of mutual independence and pair-wise independence? Though I was unsure how to make my argument rigorous/precise or how to provide a counter example.

I guess I am trying to understand whether $ X \perp (Y,W) \mid Z$ and $(X \perp Y\mid Z) \ \& \ (X \perp W \mid Z)$ are logically equivalent. They seem exactly the same to me but I can't seem to be sure of it, hence the question here.

I.e. is it really an **iff** relationship?

Comment: have you solved your question?